# Home wireless network: a device loses connection when other device is being used

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, home-networking, ipad

I have a small home wireless network utilized by a number of devices. Whenever iPad is being used for streaming youtube videos, my MacBook Pro (OS X 10.11.6) completely loses connection. 
This does not happen though when some other device (phones, other laptops) is being used instead of the iPad.

Where do I start debugging?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart hi, Tim. It's Arris DG1670A Touchstone Docsis 3.0 Wireless 16x4 Cable Modem Router Gateway

Comment: Hmm, it's a triple play device right? Lemme look it up and see what I can find. I personally would be looking there. Arris doesn't have a great track record

Comment: Can you go into your router settings and see if it's in a mixed network security mode? If it's running both tkip and aes choose only aes. It's a known bug with Arris modems and Apple products.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart currently, wireless security mode setting is WPA2-PSK(AES).